# Falsify model on empty array situation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new in front end world and I have an edit function that is receiving a model parameter as:

```
EditDatesAndSalary(profileClient: ProfileClientPeriod) {
    this.salary.setValue(profileClient.profileClientSalary[0].amount) 
 }
```

ProfileClientPeriod model:

```
export class ProfileClientPeriod {
    id: number;
    contractStartingDate? : Date;
    contractEndDate? : Date;
    profileClientSalary: Salary[];
}

export class Salary {
clientId: number;
profileId: number;
amount: number;
startDate: Date;
endDate: Date;
}
```

As you can see, the `ProfileClientPeriod` model has an Array of Salary model, and in function, I'm looking for `profileClientSalary` inside the `ProfileClientPeriod` model.

But that array can be null so it throws an error when trying to execute the function

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'amount')

So I try to create a default model for it on the function:

```
EditDatesAndSalary(profileClient: ProfileClientPeriod) {
    if(profileClient.profileClientSalary.length === 0) {
      let defaultProfileClientSalary = {
        clientId: null,
        profileId: null,
        amount: 0.00,
        startDate: null,
        endDate: null,
      }
      profileClient.profileClientSalary.push(defaultProfileClientSalary)
    }
    this.salary.setValue(profileClient.profileClientSalary[0].amount)
}
```

But now the function throws an error:

> Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible

Is this the correct way to solve this kind of issue, how can I solve the not extensible error?

I also tried to specify the model as follows:

```
 let defaultProfileClientSalary: Salary = {
        clientId: null,
        profileId: null,
        amount: 0.00,
        startDate: null,
        endDate: null,
      }

 profileClient.profileClientSalary.push(defaultProfileClientSalary)
```

But it is the same problem.

`profileClient` object before throwing the error on the push function:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I tried to replicate the model and push it as:

```
  profileClient.profileClientSalary =  Object.assign([], profileClient.profileClientSalary);
      profileClient.profileClientSalary.push(defaultProfileClientSalary)
```

But now is throwing:

> Cannot assign to read only property 'profileClientSalary' of object
> '[object Object]'

Comment: Use `console.log(profileClient)` to verify that data in that variable is as expected.

Comment: I added an image of how it looks before throws the error on the `push` function @vanowm

Comment: And before it attempts `setValue`?

Comment: The error is before `setValue`, the error occurs when it tries to push @vanowm

Comment: Hmmm it seems the object received by `EditDatesAndSalary` was marked as [`not extensible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible). You'll need find out how to update `profileClient` data.

Answer (score 0):

After searching 3 hours on the internet, I found a workaround using `cloneDeep` to clone the read-only model, and it works:

```
EditDatesAndSalary(profileClient: ProfileClientPeriod) {
    this.startDatelog.setValue(profileClient.contractStartingDate)
    const profileClientCopy = cloneDeep(profileClient)

      if(!profileClientCopy.profileClientSalary || profileClientCopy.profileClientSalary.length === 0) {
      let defaultProfileClientSalary: Salary = {
        clientId: null,
        profileId: null,
        amount: 0,
        startDate: null,
        endDate: null,
      }
      profileClientCopy.profileClientSalary.push(defaultProfileClientSalary)
    }
    this.salary.setValue(profileClientCopy.profileClientSalary[0].amount)
}
```